# How to retrieve the query string in the HiveMetastoreListener?

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hive-metastore

I am trying to create a listener on the HiveMetastore where i need to retrieve the query submitted to the metastore. Is there any way to retrieve the queryString?
In the MetatstoreListener we get events such as `onCreate`,  `onDelete` etc.
It is possible to have `postHook` on the hive but need to have the listener on the metastore so that all the DDL commands are getting catched executed from anywhere
Is there any way to capture the events in the Metastore and apply the same events to another parallel Metastore setup?

context:- I am trying to upgrade the hive from `1.x` version to `3.x.x`
where the idea is to have the stateless setup of Metastore-service in Kubernetes.
but not sure how much the query syntax is compatible between both versions. So wanted to set hot-hot setup parallelly and monitor the results of queries.  So if there is any way on the MetastoreListener to transfer the `DDL` events from one Metastore to another and execute simultaneously?

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.events.AlterTableEvent;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreEventListener;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.events.CreateTableEvent;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
public class HiveMetastoreListener extends MetaStoreEventListener {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HiveMetastoreListener.class);
    private static final  ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private final DataProducer dataProducer = DataProducer.getInstance();
    public HiveMetastoreListener(Configuration config) {
        super(config);
       
    }

    /**
     * Handler for a CreateTable Event
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreateTable(CreateTableEvent tableEvent) throws MetaException{
        super.onCreateTable(tableEvent);
            try {
                String data = null;

                dataProducer.produceToKafka("metastore_topic", LocalDateTime.now().toString(), data);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error:- " + e);
            }




    }
```

Comment: I don't think Hive Metastore has a concept of `queryString` as its operaton is RPC-based. Parsing `queryString`s happens on the client side.

Comment: Is there any way to capture the events in the Metastore and apply the same events to another parallel Metastore setup?

context:- I am trying to upgrade the hive from 1.x version to 3.x.
where the idea is to have the stateless setup of Metastore-service in Kubernetes.
but we are not sure how much the query syntax or compatible between both versions. So wanted to set hot-hot setup parallelly and monitor the results of queries.  So if there is any way on the MetastoreListener to transfer the `DDL` events from one Metastore to another and execute simultaneously?